# How to debug service workers in firefox?

Tags: debugging, firefox, service-worker

Debugging service workers in FF seems ridiculously painful.
I know that from main page I can

- go in the Application panel,
- click onto "aboutdebugging",
- search the new page for my worker among 200 others,
- click start
- click inspect then
- I got to look for two consoles instead of one and passing
  messages between the 2 is non trivial.

Tell me there's an easier way!

Comment: also see [debugging-service-workers](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/application/service_workers/index.html#debugging-service-workers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a nightly version to have a debug link near the worker.js in the application panel.
In the stable version, there's only a link that displays the source of the worker.js in a new tab. How useful is that?